# Can't load a JKS keystore containing

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, x509

I'm trying to load a JKS keystore containing an intermediate CA certificate acquired from an existing web server.

The Verisign certificate is shown below.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have imported the certificate into a JKS keystore using the following command:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias vs -file vs.cer -keystore vs.jks -storepass changeit -storetype JKS
```

I have verified that keytool can read the certificate details back from the newly created keystore.

Finally, I am using the following Java code to load the keystore:

```
final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");   
trustStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("vs.jks"); 
trustStore.load(trustStream, "changeit".toCharArray());
```

Currently using JDK 1.7.0_51.

Unfortunately, an exception is thrown while in the load() method.

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: X500 RDN
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:171)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1788)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:202)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:97)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:747)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)

    ...

Caused by: java.io.IOException: X500 RDN
    at sun.security.x509.RDN.<init>(RDN.java:242)
    at sun.security.x509.X500Name.parseDER(X500Name.java:804)
    at sun.security.x509.X500Name.<init>(X500Name.java:307)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateIssuerName.<init>(CertificateIssuerName.java:82)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:685)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169)
    ... 37 more
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

I have the feeling that there is something unexpected in the certificate which is confusing the parser. The stack trace suggests that there may be a problem parsing the issuer name.

Is there anything I can do to work around this?

Comment: What does keytool -list -v print?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have figured out the cause. Nothing wrong with the certificate file or the keystore!

I'm using Maven to compile my project, which is automatically copying the jks file to the target build directory.

It turned out that, during the copying process, Maven assumed the file was a text file, and "helpfully" converted any extended ASCII characters (>= 0x80) to '?' (0x3F)!

When analysing / listing the JKS file, I naturally only looked in my source directory and never thought to verify that the resource file be identical in content!

Confirms the golden rule, Never Trust Maven!

I solved this by adding the following to my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <nonFilteredFileExtensions>                            
                <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: X500 RDN
```

I had a little look back in the history of our mercurial repo and it is pretty clear that a merge was done of various keystores when changes from a similar repo (different release) were pulled in. The outcome was that all of those keystores that were "merged" were in fact corrupted.

A manual copy of the affected files between the repos resolved the issue.